# 2 Event Horizons come into contact

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Just a question out of curiosity, what would happen if the event horizons of 2 black holes of the same mass were to come into contact? Would both gravitational accelerations be canceled where the event horizons overlap?

Comment: Duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39253/

Comment: Note that black hole mergers are the prime suspect for [long-duration gamma-ray bursts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst) (see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4869) (arXiv preprint), for example). The infalling BHs also would generate gravitational waves that [LIGO](http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/) ought to be able to detect.