# Could one or more black holes be used to pull something out of another black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

Could a second black hole be used to create a gradient that reaches into the event horizon of a first black hole so that what's inside it can escape through the gradient?

Maybe you would have to use a lot of black holes and be able to plot or control their position precisely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for one black hole to pull an object out of another black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39253/)

Comment: John, yeah. I can't say it's the answer I was hoping for though.